# How to use standard toolbar icons with WxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython, icons

I'm designing a simple text editor using WxPython, and I want to put the platform's native icons in the toolbar.  It seems that the only way to make toolbars is with custom images, which are not good for portability. Is there some kind of (e.g.) GetSaveIcon()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think wxPython provides native images on each platform
but just for consistency sake you can use wx.ArtProvider
e.g.
wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_FILE_OPEN)

Comment: alternatively if ArtProvider doesn't return native images you can customize it for each platform